# Converting NOT IN to NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle

Having a nightmare of a time understanding the usage of NOT EXISTS, primarily how to convert my NOT IN solution below so that I can actually understand how I achieved the results.
Have several articles on askTom, the oracle forums and stackoverflow, but can't find anything that clearly helps understand this problem. My apologies if I have missed it through my noobish searching.

```
SELECT s.S_Fname, s.S_Lname
FROM STUDENT s
WHERE s.S_Sex = 'F'
AND S.S_Id NOT IN(SELECT e.S_Id
        FROM ENROLLMENT e
        WHERE e.Mark < 70);
```

Bit of assistance with the content, trying to find female students who have never received a mark below 70 in any class they have been enrolled in.

Answer (score 18):

It's rather simple, when you get the hang of it:

```
SELECT s.S_Fname, s.S_Lname
FROM STUDENT s
WHERE s.S_Sex = 'F'
AND S.S_Id NOT IN(SELECT e.S_Id           -- take this line
        FROM ENROLLMENT e
        WHERE e.Mark < 70);
```

That line basically compares `S.S_Id` with all the `e.S_Id` values that come from the subquery.

Now change that to `NOT EXISTS` and put an equality check `S.S_Id = e.S_Id`, inside the subquery:

```
SELECT s.S_Fname, s.S_Lname
FROM STUDENT s
WHERE s.S_Sex = 'F'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT e.S_Id          
        FROM ENROLLMENT e
        WHERE (e.Mark < 70)       -- if this is complex, you'll need parentheses
        AND S.S_Id = e.S_Id);
```

Minor possible change is to realize that `(SELECT e.S_Id ...` does not really need the `e.S_Id`. Subqueries with `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` just check if there are rows returned or not and the column values do not matter. You can put `SELECT *` or a constant there (`SELECT 1` is common) or `SELECT NULL` or even `SELECT 1/0` (Yes, that will work!):

```
SELECT s.S_Fname, s.S_Lname
FROM STUDENT s
WHERE s.S_Sex = 'F'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM ENROLLMENT e
        WHERE e.Mark < 70  
        AND S.S_Id = e.S_Id);
```

Another major consideration is that when you do the conversion this way, the (seemingly equivalent) `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` writings of a query are really equivalent only if both `S_Id` columns are not nullable. If the `e.S_Id` column is nullable, the `NOT IN` may result in the whole query to return no rows at all (because `x NOT IN (a, b, c, ...)` is equivalent to `x<>a AND x<>b AND ...` and that condition cannot be true when one of the `a,b,c...` is `NULL`.)

For similar reasons, you will have different results if the `s.S_Id` is nullable (that's not very likely in this case as it's probably the primary key but in other cases it matters.)

So it's almost always better to use `NOT EXISTS`, as it behaves differently even if either column is nullable (the `S.S_Id = e.S_Id` check will discard rows with null earlier) and usually this behaviour is the wanted one. There are many details in the question: **[NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists/11074428#11074428)**, in the answer by @Martin Smith. You will also find there ways to convert the `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS` and keep the null related (unpleasant) behaviour.

Comment: Wonderful! You're right, it makes perfect sense now when looking at the solution. The not exists clause is a bit of a pain at first glance, but once you understand how to eliminate the unnecessary rows, works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: +1 [They also have different behaviour if `S.S_Id` is nullable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists/11074428#11074428)

Comment: You might like to note that in many cases the optimiser will transform them to the same execution plan anyway -- I think that would only be the case where e.s_id is not null, which is another good reason for making sure that is is (not null).

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you asked for, but here's a way you could do this without `NOT EXISTS` - create the 'achievers below 70' as a derived table, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` it and check for nulls like this...

```
SELECT s.S_Fname, s.S_Lname 
FROM STUDENT s
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT S_Id 
  FROM ENROLLMENT
  WHERE Mark < 70
) e ON e.S_Id = s.S_Id
WHERE e.S_Id IS NULL 
AND s.S_Sex = 'F';
```

Might also help for your general SQL understanding. There are pros & cons to both approaches.

[`Click here to go to SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f275b/1)

Comment: I don't see the "NOT EXISTS" part in your query. OP wants to learn about "NOT EXISTS".

Comment: It's just an alternative solution to help broaden the OP's understanding of SQL.