# How Do I Write An Equivalent Query Without The Usage Of The Exists Keyword, So I Can Translate It To Relational Algebra?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
    select daa.*
    from Dataa daa
    where not exists (select row() from Stuff)
```

Basically, when Stuff has data in it, the query returns nothing.
However, when Stuff is empty, the query returns everything in Dataa. I need to rewrite this query with the same behavior, but without the exists keyword, so that I can translate it into Relational Algebra.

Some resources I've looked at are:

[Converting NOT IN to NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707229/converting-not-in-to-not-exists)
http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Translating_SQL_to_Relational_Algebra#EXISTS_in_the_Where_Clause_.28by_example.29

Comment: Have you forgotten a `NOT` in your query? Otherwise the description doesn't match.

Comment: I absolutely must have edited it out of the question on accident. The question has been updated!

Comment: anti-join, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few way to write it without `Exists`

```
select daa.*
from Dataa daa
where (select 1 from Stuff limit 1) is null

select daa.*
from Dataa daa
where (select count(*) from Stuff) = 0

select daa.*
from Dataa daa
left outer join (select 1 one1 from Stuff)j on 1=1
where j.one1 is null
```

but I do not see what exactly is the problem with that keyword.